# Limit Cython CPU and RAM usage?

Tags: python, performance, cython

Recently I installed Cython and use it to speed up my python program (primality test). As I give a small number, it works fine and runs much faster. But giving such a huge number, my computer started to freeze as both CPU and RAM reach 100%.

Is there a way to limit Cython CPU and RAM usage?

Here's my code by the way (in Cython language):

```
from math import *

cpdef trial_factoring(float M, float p, list bits_list):
    cdef float t
    t = sqrt((M+1)*2)

    cdef float k_range
    k_range = (t-1)//(2*p)

    cdef float k
    k = 1 

    cdef list potential_filter
    potential_filter = []                   

    cdef float potential

    while k <= k_range:
        potential = 2*k*p + 1
        if potential % 8 == 3 or potential % 8 == 5:
            pass
        else:
            potential_filter.append(potential)
        k += 1

    cdef int a
    a = 1   

    cdef int factor
    cdef int i

    for factor in potential_filter:
        for i in range(len(bits_list)):
            a *= a                  
            if bits_list[i] == 1:        
                a *= 2              
                a %= factor         

        if a == 1:                  
            return False            

    return True
```

Comment: Try dockerizing your application and setting the CPU & memory limit for your container

Comment: OK, I'll try to do it. Thanks!

Comment: If you are running on Linux, you can mitigate the issues by changing the priority of the python process and by disabling the swap (respectively using the commands `nice` and `swapoff`).